# Google Calendar: Invited to recurring event, how to mark as free?

Tags: google-calendar

If I'm invited to an recurring event on Google Calendar, how can I mark myself as "free" for the whole series and not only for individual events? If I click on one event in the series and edit my status to "free", this only applies to this one event? Using GApps for Enterpries on the Google Webclient in case that matters.

Comment: What you ask for Google Calendar recurring events is not a native Google Calendar functionality. I suggest you can request Google to add this via https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6110973?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: In https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/settings?hl=en you can change general setting Automatically add invitations to "No, only show invitations to which I have responded".

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 13 times.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for Google Calendar recurring events is not a native Google Calendar functionality. I suggest you can request Google to add this via [Google Support](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6110973?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

In [Google Calendar settings](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/settings?hl=en) you can change general setting ***Automatically add invitations*** to "No, only show invitations to which I have responded".

Comment: I don't understand your anwer: I'm not speaking about accepting invitations, I'm speaking about setting free/busy for an invite I accepted. Second, I'm not sure what you are saying with "Google Calendar recurring events is not a native Google Calendar functionality". I think it is, it is supported on their WebApp and their MobilApp.

Comment: Setting "free" status for an invite you accepted for recurring events is not a native Google Calendar functionality. You can however change your general Google Calendar setting and disable automatically adding invitations to your calendar unless you respond explicitely to them.